# Scala Play Framework: Passing an array to a view

Tags: scala, playframework

I am generating an array from json:

```
val product_array:Option[Any] = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(products_json)
```

And then I want to pass it to a view like this:

```
Ok(views.html.payment(product_array))
```

In the "payment.scala.html" view I am wondering what to put on the top of the view. Something like this:

```
@(product_array: Array)
```

But that is not correct. What do I put on the top of the view?

Second question:

How do I loop through that array in the view "payment.scala.html"?

Comment: Did you finally found a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Scala or Play expert so I don't know if you're able to pass an array, or if in your specific case if you're required to use an array, but I know you're allowed to pass a List[Type] so potentially you could use a List rather than an Array would be one option. If you go about it this way it would simply be

```
@(class_list: List[Class]
```

And then to traverse it would simply be

```
@for(class <- class_list){
```

And then to access the current iteration would be

```
@class.doStuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaJson), for parsing, why don't you use:

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(jsonString)
```

and then pass it to your view, and then, navigate through the Json tree ?